# Connecting objects with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

I’m trying to master tkinter in Python-3. I read some tutorials and have a working window made of 4 classes. (MenuBar class, ToolBar class, Main class and StatusBar class). These classes are instantiated from one main class (MainWindow).

I can run the script with no errors, but I’m stuck with the interaction between the objects. I would like to run a method from the 'main' object when I select something in the 'menubar' object. What’s the correct way to do this, or should I change the architecture of the script to make this possible? - Lets say I want to execute change_main from within the menubar.

I have been looking at static and class methods, but I don't know how to access the instances. I would like to be able to access the 'main' instance from within the 'menubar' instance. All instances are created in the MainWindow class.

**EDITED: CODE UPDATED**

*I added a controller method in the MainWindow class and passed the mainwindow object to the menubar object. In the menubar object the controller method is called by command=controller.controller`_`test as mentioned by  stovfl. The controller`_`test method calls the change`_`main method in the main object. Directly calling parent.main.change`_`main did not work as the main object is instantiated after the menubar object.*

```py
    import tkinter as tk

    class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            parent.title("Application Title")
            parent.geometry("500x400")

            self.menubar = MenuBar(parent, controller=self)
            self.toolbar = ToolBar(parent)
            self.main = Main(parent)
            self.statusbar = StatusBar(parent, 'status shown here...')

        def controller_test(self):
            self.main.change_main()


    class MenuBar(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller=None):
            menu = tk.Menu(parent)
            parent.config(menu=menu)
            submenu = tk.Menu(menu, tearoff=False)
            menu.add_cascade(label='File', menu=submenu)
            submenu.add_command(label='Test', command=controller.controller_test)


    class ToolBar(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent):…


    class StatusBar(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, message=''):…


    class Main(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.main = tk.Frame(parent, bg='black')
            self.main.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
            label.pack()

        def change_main(self, event=None):
            self.main.pack_forget()
            self.main = tk.Frame(self.parent, bg='blue')
            self.main.pack(fill='both', expand=True)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = tk.Tk()
        MainWindow(root)
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should add the full code of `ToolBar` class, so we can see what you are doing and help.

Comment: You have to use `command=parent.main.change_main`.

Comment: *"calling parent.main.change_main did not work"*: You have change `self.main = Main(parent)` to `self.main = Main(self)` also.